# How do you delete empty files with a specific ending (.gff)?

Tags: python, delete-file

I an pretty new to python and have been given a problem to solve in my lab, how could one possibly **remove specific files ending with .gff** or another ending **if the file is empty**? The files were all just created and are all in the same directory.

Comment: What is that script/code? That's not Python.

Comment: Do you want a response in Python? Also, are all these files in the same directory?

Comment: look at the `glob`  and `os` libraries

Comment: If you're in linux, try `find -name "*.gff" -empty -delete`.

Answer (score 0):

for getting files of a particular kind out of a directory `glob` works very well `glob.glob("./file/path/*.gff")` will return a list of files ending in .gff

as for finding the size of the file use `os.stat("./file/path/blah.gff").st_size`